# redefinition of unused function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, importerror

I have 2 python files in the same folder **`utils.py`** and **`preprocessing.py`**.

I have two functions defined in **utils.py** file: **`preprocess_text, text2seq_generator`**

I need to use these `functions` in `preprocessing.py`. But I'm getting unable to import and warning saying redefinition of unused preprocess_text from line 19

Code:

**utils.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
#import pdb


def filter_text(text):
    return ''.join([c for c in text if c not in punctuation]).lower()

def preprocess_text(file_path_src, file_path_tar, max_feats):
    f_src = open(file_path_src)
    f_tar = open(file_path_tar)
    vocab = defaultdict(int)
    freq_src = defaultdict(int)
    freq_tar = defaultdict(int)
    sents_src = [line.rstrip() for line in f_src.readlines()]
    sents_tar = [line.rstrip() for line in f_tar.readlines()]

    for sent in sents_src:
        sent = filter_text(sent)
        for word in sent.split():
            freq_src[word] += 1

   for sent in sents_tar:
       for word in sent.split():
           freq_tar[word] += 1

   freq_sorted_src = Counter(freq_src)
   freq_sorted_src = freq_sorted_src.most_common(max_feats)
   freq_sorted_tar = Counter(freq_tar)
   freq_sorted_tar = freq_sorted_tar.most_common(max_feats)

   freq_words_src = map(lambda x:x[0], freq_sorted_src)
   freq_words_tar = map(lambda x:x[0], freq_sorted_tar)

   vocab_src = dict({v:k for k, v in enumerate(freq_words_src)})
   vocab_tar = dict({v:k for k, v in enumerate(freq_words_tar)})

   vocab_src["UNK"] = max_feats
   vocab_src["<s>"] = max_feats + 1
   vocab_src["</s>"] = max_feats + 2

   vocab_tar["UNK"] = max_feats
   vocab_tar["<s>"] = max_feats + 1
   vocab_tar["</s>"] = max_feats + 2
   #pdb.set_trace()
   return vocab_src, vocab_tar, sents_src, sents_tar


def text2seq_generator(vocab_src, vocab_tar, sents_src, sents_tar):
    unk_key = vocab_src["UNK"]
    for sent_src, sent_tar in zip(sents_src, sents_tar):
        seq_src = map(lambda x:vocab_src.get(x, unk_key), filter_text(sent_src).split())
        seq_tar = map(lambda x:vocab_tar.get(x, unk_key), sent_tar.split())
        #pdb.set_trace()
        yield seq_src, seq_tar


 #vs, vt, ss, st = preprocess_text('../data/training.hi-en.en', '../data/training.hi-en.hi', 5000)
 #for x,y in text2seq_generator(vs, vt, ss, st):
 #print(y)
```

**preprocessing.py file:**

```
  from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
  from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
  import codecs
  import pdb
  import numpy as np
  from utils import preprocess_text,text2seq_generator
```

**Error :**

```
  from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
  from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
  import codecs
  import pdb
  import numpy as np
  from utils import preprocess_text

  Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-8-335a30ab7871>", line 6, in <module>
from utils import preprocess_text

  ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocess_text'
```

**warning:**

```
   redefinition of unused preprocess_text from line 19
```

Comment: import .py file and use the function.you could do "from utils import preprocessing "

Comment: Lots of broken indentation in your code. Also, too much code - show the minimum code that still generates your error

Comment: @Prakash047 still the same error

Comment: @vmg the code is reduced, two functions in one python file needs to be used in another file

Comment: does utils have a parent folder? in that try from "parent.utils import preprocessing" Also try placing __init__.py in utils folder if you are using python2.x

Comment: I need to import , 'preprocess_text' a function from Util.py file and I want to use that function in Preprocessing.py file

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your question? Are you able to import the other function `text2seq_generator`? Are there only function definitions in `utils.py` or is there also some other scripting?

Comment: I have totally 3 functions in `utils.py`, I need to use 2 functions `preprocess_text`, 'text2seq_generator` in preprocessing.py. Both files are in the same folder

Comment: Do you run the script via the command line or in a python IDE?

Comment: Did you by any chance install another module called `utils`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, because, initially it was throwing error for utils. Is it because of this causing problem?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren python IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have another package called `utils` somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH` that conflicts with your current file.

You can explicitly load your module from its path with the `importlib` module.

Add these lines to `preprocessing.py` (python 3.3 and 3.4):

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

utils = SourceFileLoader("utils", "/path/to/utils.py").load_module()
utils.preprocess_text(...)
```

For python3.5+, you should use:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("utils", "/path/to/utils.py")
utils = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(utils)
utils.preprocess_text(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, i did not get `utils.preprocess_text(....)` part, preprocess_text is a function which is the file `util.py`, and it need to be used across various other .py files

Comment: @Anagha Did you try it? Once you load the module, you can access it with `moduleName.function()`.

Comment: Well, a syntax error means you'll need to fix it. What error is it? You're on python3 I assume?

Comment: yes python 3, i used the same `utils.preprocess_text(...)` followed by the fuction body.

Comment: No! Just remove that line. Now try calling your function like: `utils.preprocess_text(param1, param2, param3)`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I have filled it with the necessary structure

Comment: You must add these lines where you want to import utils (preprocessing.py), not inside utils.

Comment: Yes, I have added in preprocessing.py file. I need to import utils inside preprocessing.py file

Comment: @Anagha I tried it and it works. What problems are you facing?

Comment: Its working now, thank you for the help. Albeit i'm facing a different error now.

Comment: @Anagha No problem. You can mark this answer accepted if it solved this particular query. You can ask another question for your new problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You run it from a python IDE (instead of running it from the commandline). Then the IDE (at least with spyder this is the case) will look in your `path` environmental variable for the `utils.py` script. Which most likely isn't there.

**Solution 1**

Add these lines at the start of your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'directory_of_utils.py_script')
from utils import preprocess_text, text2seq_generator
```

Or just change your working directory:

```
import os
os.chdir('directory_of_utils.py_script')
from utils import preprocess_text, text2seq_generator
```

**Option 2**

You already installed the module `utils`. Therefore, the script will try to find the function `preprocess_text` in this module (BTW: this will not happen if you run it via the commandline).

**Solution 2**

Rename `utils.py` (And if running from IDE add the lines from solution 1!).

Comment: Thank you, but neither of them worked.
its throwing `ImportError: No module named 'utils1'`

Comment: and the combination of 1 and 2? your working directory most likely is not the same as the directory of your `utils1.py` script

Comment: How did you check that? This literally works on my pc when I use the script you provided (even if I have the module `utils` installed).

Comment: I used 
`import os`
`os.getcwd()`